# Pale green areas in new leaves of Draceana fragrans, disease?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, dracaena

Does anyone know whats wrong with my draceana? All the new leaves have those "pale green" areas, they have it already in the beginning. I´m familiar with the common pests and they are not the cause. All the old leaves seems healthy. The plants get plenty of indirect sunlight, and I water it only when the soil is dryed. I have seen the same symptoms in other tall "Rikki"s, I have met in my work as a plant carer, but no-one know the cause for this or could it be treated.

"Sick leaf"
[image: Sick leaf]

"Healthy leaf for comparison"
[image: Healthy leaf for comparison]

Comment: You're talking about the mottled/variable shades of green, correct? Not the vertical yellow-ish lines down the middle of the leaf, right? The lines appear to be variegation, varying shades of green in a leaf. The mottled part is a mystery to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the mottled parts. It seems that no-one knows reasons for this. Maybe I just need to try some stuff, e.g. give more nutrients or something.Today I made one experiment, I mixed small amount of ash from my fireplace with water and watered the plant with it.

Comment: My 50 year old dracaena has the same markings ; doesn't seem to bother it. (It has been cut and reroofed uncountable times - including yesterday, l am little getting plants out this spring.)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a little more and the only explanation for mottled leaves i could find is a virus that is apparently not curable. See link below. See if the symptoms match what you are seeing.

[Dracaenea virus](https://www.westcoastnurseries.com/dracaena-signs-of-common-dracaena-diseases/)

The only other common thread I could find in descriptions of diseases/conditions for this species is lack of air circulation.